# Is it possible to plot multiline chart on Python ggplot?

Tags: python, pandas, python-ggplot

I need to plot 3 columns of a Pandas dataframe on python ggplot, with the same index. Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you want something in ggplot that replicates something like this in matplotlib.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10), 'b': range(5,15), 'c': range(7,17)})
df.plot()
```

ggplot expects the data to be in 'long' format, so you need to do a little reshaping, with `melt`.  It also currently does not support plotting the index, so that needs to made into a column.

```
from ggplot import ggplot, geom_line, aes
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10), 'b': range(5,15), 'c': range(7,17)})

df['x'] = df.index
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='x')

ggplot(aes(x='x', y='value', color='variable'), df) + \
      geom_line()
```

Comment: How can you add labels here to indicate variable colors?

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of ggplot, it's even easier:

```
from ggplot import ggplot, geom_line, aes
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10), 'b': range(5, 15), 'c': range(7, 17)})
df['x'] = df.index
ggplot(aes(x='x'), data=df) +\
    geom_line(aes(y='a'), color='blue') +\
    geom_line(aes(y='b'), color='red') +\
    geom_line(aes(y='c'), color='green')
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have a secondary axis?  I've seen references to sec.axis, but I can't get it to work in the python environment

Comment: Not sure - perhaps look for inspiration on the R tutorials for ggplot, or the examples for Python ggplot?

Comment: Yeah, I'm struggling with it now.  Did you have trouble with your matplotlib package after you installed ggplot?

Comment: To be honest, I ended up using matplotlib for a bunch of graphs, as you can do anything you want with matplotlib. I think its almost worth the learning curve of learning a new API.