# How to plot multiple y variables using ggplot (Python)

Tags: python, time-series, facet, python-ggplot

I have the following data in a Pandas data frame:

```
Company     Date                 Revenue     Profit
ABC         08/21/16 00:00:00    500         300
ABC         08/22/16 00:00:00    600         200
ABC         08/23/16 00:00:00    650         400
ABC         08/24/16 00:00:00    625         450
ABC         08/25/16 00:00:00    675         500
ABC         08/26/16 00:00:00    680         410
XYZ         08/21/16 00:00:00    300         290
XYZ         08/22/16 00:00:00    510         400
XYZ         08/23/16 00:00:00    490         450
XYZ         08/24/16 00:00:00    475         270
XYZ         08/25/16 00:00:00    610         500
XYZ         08/26/16 00:00:00    400         250
```

I'm interested in building a line plot to show how the 'Revenue' and 'Profit' variables for companies ABC and XYZ evolve over time using a **facet grid**, as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Files\\Projections', sep = ',')
df.columns = ['Company',
              'Date',
              'Revenue',
              'Profit']
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors = 'coerce')
ggplot(df, aes(x='Date')) + \
    geom_line(aes(y='Revenue'), color='blue') + \
    geom_line(aes(y='Profit'), color='red') + \
    xlab("date") + ylab("value") + ggtitle("Projections")) + \
    scale_x_date() + \
    facet_wrap('Company', scales='free')
```

Firstly, is it even *possible* to use facet_wrap in this case?

If so, then I understand that I have to use `melt` (presumably because the data has to be in 'long' format).  But, at this point, I don't understand how or why (even after reviewing this issue:  [Is it possible to plot multiline chart on Python ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24478925/is-it-possible-to-plot-multiline-chart-on-python-ggplot)).

I thought that it would be possible to just use:

```
geom_line(aes(y='Revenue'), color='blue') + \ 
geom_line(aes(y='Profit'), color='red')
```

to plot the 'revenue' and 'profit' variables. But, that results in the following error message.

`GgplotError: u'geom_line requires the following missing aesthetics: y'`

Does anyone know how to resolve this **without** using `melt`?  Or, if it's absolutely necessary to use `melt`, then perhaps set me straight on exactly how to do so in the example I provided above?

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to solve this (even tried to use Seaborn, but there is a bug in x-axis dates there!).  Any help is much appreciated.

I'd even be open to just using Matplotlib for this...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you look at the "meat" examples towards the bottom of the `geom_line` [docs](http://ggplot.yhathq.com/docs/geom_line.html)?  I haven't used Python ggplot but that looks similar to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @BrenBarn -- Yes, I've looked at the "meat" examples.  What is the 'color' in my case?  Very confused...

Comment: I believe the data is already in melted form (i.e. in 'long' form), is it not?  Why do I need to use melt?